# HTML CSS Email grid not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, email, vml

I have an email template that works perfectly on non-desktop versions of Outlook. However, when rendering on Outlook it looks terrible.
This part of the email is a card (it will contain several cards in the future, but for simplicity purposes I only have one here), issue is the width (on Outlook) is taking the full width available, instead of just a piece (on non-outlook the width is set to 200px (row 4)).
How can I achieve the Grid view (4 cards per row) on Outlook as well (grid values on row 2):

-->

```
    <!--[if mso]> 
    <tr>
        <td width="20px" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; margin-top: 50px; max-height: 500px;">
    <![endif]-->
    
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Image1" style="width:50%; border-radius: 20px;">
      </a>
        <!--[if !mso]>-->
        <div>
        <!--<![endif]-->

        <!--[if mso]>
        <tr>
            <td class="container">
        <![endif]-->

            <h4><b>My Card 1</b></h4> 
            <p style="font-size: 15px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum interdum bibendum arcu quis molestie. Duis at pretium justo, at egestas leo. Quisque gravida, est sit amet blandit sagittis, lorem...</p> 
            <p style="font-size: 15px"><b>Date: 08/15/2023</b></p>
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com/" style="font-size: 15px;">Read More</a></p>

            <br><br>
                <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <button style="positions: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: #6D925C; color: white; height: 50px; width: 150px; padding: 0; border: none;" type="button">Register</button>
                </a>
        <!--[if !mso]>-->
        </div>
        <!--<![endif]-->

        <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <![endif]-->
        

    <!--[if mso]> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if !mso]>-->
    </div>
    <!--<![endif]-->

</td>
```

thank you

Comment: The HTML rendering engines for online clients are often very different than desktop-native versions. Even with the online clients, you'll find a lot of discrepancies and limitations. You may not be able to get around this problem, short of providing a "View this email in your browser" link.

Comment: You say in your text that "the the width is set to 200px" but there is no width set to 200px in the code you show us. Please include all of the relevant code (but only the relevant code) so we can see why that isn't working and be able to help. See how to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Email templates are notoriously difficult because of how they are treated differently by email clients.

Answer (score -1):

Try using @media screen. You can always use media queries for resizing problems on different screens. This is a good helpful site that can show you how to use them properly and how to apply them to your site. Good luck!

[Using Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries)